# Magento 2 - How to add video icon in dot if the gallery has video?

Tags: magento2, product, class, gallery, video

[image]

I want to add **video-icon** class in dot if the gallery has video.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be with JS, by targeting the Video frame that is active, in order to find the dot that is active at the same time.

Fotorama video class: "fotorama__stage__frame fotorama-video-container ... fotorama__active ..."

Dot active class: "fotorama__nav__frame fotorama__nav__frame--dot fotorama__active"

Then customize that specific dot (add a class, add icon, etc).